# Calling a class in p5 that won't loop?

Tags: javascript, class, object, processing, p5.js

I’m currently working on a game with p5 which will include some pretty complicated stuff… at least for me anyway.

How do I call a class without it looping in p5?

Consider my following code:

```
function draw() {
  lumberjack.clicked();
}

class Lumberjack {
  constructor(x, y, br, bg, bb, dr, dg, db) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.br = br,
    this.bg = bg,
    this.bb = bb,
    this.dr = dr,
    this.dg = dg,
    this.db = db
  }
  body() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.br, this.bg, this.bb);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 40);
    fill(this.dr, this.dg, this.db);
    rect(this.x + 4, this.y - 2, 2, 35);
    rect(this.x + 14, this.y - 2, 2, 35);
    rect(this.x, this.y + 30, 20, 10);
    fill(91, 51, 0);
    rect(this.x, this.y + 30, 20, 2);
    fill(255);
    rect(this.x + 9, this.y + 30, 2, 2);
  }
  move() {

  }
  clicked() {
    let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x + 10, this.y + 20);
    if (d < 20) {
      console.log("I'm a lumberjack and I'm ok");
    }
  }
}
```

If I click on my lumberjack an infinite loop of console.logs starts.

The only way I could sort of figure out how to solve this is to put my function call in a mousePressed() function but then my console.log is still called twice.

Can I call classes without having them loop?

Thanks in advance!

Max

Comment: Your class isn't looping by itself, but `draw()` is of course called in a loop (unless you use `noLoop()`)

Comment: Precisely. If I call the class.function within draw() it'll loop. I if I use the noLoop() function everything will stop looping and I need most of the other classes to loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [mouse clicked](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseClicked) function.

```
function draw() {
  lumberjack.draw() // do something to draw the lumberjack
}

function mouseClicked(e) {
  lumberjack.clicked() // handle click on canvas
}
```

Comment: Sorted. Thanks!

Comment: What about drawing non-looping objects on the canvas?